# Pin Button on 3d Object in ARkit

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I am trying to Pin button on a 3d object. When the TouchBegan function loads, I use touch to place object in the world. I want the buttons to be pinned on the object when i load the object.

I am unable to find AR Button in arkit. All i can found is to place text as child node and name the node and get the first hit result and get the child node by name to triggers buttons.

The Button placing to object with relative to 3d space is an issue. Looking for possible solutions.

[image]

This is what i wanted to achieve and currently am using the github project as a demo.

https://github.com/eh3rrera/ARKitSceneKitExample

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using box/plane with SKScene as material for button and text in SKScene as title. Then you can use hitTest in tapGesture. And maybe animate color change to have button pressed effect.

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved the button problem in ARKit wast to create a physical button as part of the 3D model

[image]

you don’t need to create buttons with text, for say tapping open the door or switching a light... but you need to somehow communicate to the user they can tap (the door to open or tap a light to switch on).

To active the node you give it a unique node.name “front_door”

```
node.name = “front_door”
```

One downside is you have to do naming of nodes using xcode before the program is executed.

Below is the swift code for responding to the tap on the button on the door... using a hitTest. The door would rotate open when the button was touched.

```
let tappedNode = self.sceneView.hitTest(gesture.location(in: gesture.view), options: [:])

    if !tappedNode.isEmpty {

      let tappedName = tappedNode[0].node.name

      if tappedName == "front_door" {

       let doorNode = self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: tappedName, recursively: true)

      // rotate the door open      
      doorNode?.eulerAngles = SCNVector3Make( 0,0,Float(2*M_PI))

                }

}
```

[image]